# Finding closest coordinates between two datasets R

Tags: r

I have the two following datasets :

```r
            ID             latitude         longitude
   1:      11001           -4.356            15.33
   2:      11002           -4.355            15.36
   3:      11003           -4.360            15.33
   4:      11004           -4.363            15.33
   5:      11005           -4.367            15.33
  ---                                             
1977:      93085           -6.140            24.52
1978:      93086           -6.568            24.24
1979:      93087           -6.651            23.40
```

```r
          lon             lat
1   14.2635707899353    -1.72819041855475
2   14.6252329955268    -4.15798027488536
3   16.3987113877547    -3.45049484822612
4   17.4593940761681    -3.49348376028095
5   17.5650287350763    -3.76706898554739
  --- 
385 20.2021915511742    -9.11098960107533
386 17.5816739683535    -8.34902586674811
387 21.9970345436927    -5.38327274344268
```

I would like to find for each coordinates in dataset 1 its nearest coordinates in dataset2.

I have tried the following code :

```r
library(raster)
d <- pointDistance(data1[,3:2],data2[,1:2], lonlat=TRUE, allpairs=T)
i <- apply(d, 1, which.min)

x$SRC_ID = y$SRC_ID[i]
x$distance = d[cbind(1:nrow(d), i)]
x
```

However it gave me this error :

```r
Error in .geodist(x[i, 1], x[i, 2], y[, 1], y[, 2]) : 
  Not compatible with the requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check the types of your variables in `data1` and/or `data2`, there are characters instead of doubles somewhere.